# Set MacVim default font

Tags: vim, fonts, default

How do I set the default font for MacVim?

I have tried adding the following line

```
set guifont = Monaco:h12
```

to either of the following files:

```
~/.vimrc
~/.gvimrc
~/Applications/MacVim/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/vimrc
~/Applications/MacVim/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/gvimrc
~/Applications/MacVim/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/.vimrc
~/Applications/MacVim/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/.gvimrc
```

I restarted MacVim, but it still won't set the default font. Anything I missed?

**UPDATE:** I can issue the `set guifont` command in runtime and it works fine. It just doesn't seem to read it off my startup files.

Comment: I use a font different from the default with the above command in `~/.vimrc` and it works perfectly fine. Perhaps you might want to check if the particular font exists...

Comment: @yoda I actually tried doing `set guifont=Monaco:h12` during runtime and it works fine. I'm not sure why it doesn't read it off the startup files I mentioned.

Comment: You may use `vim -D` to enter [debug mode](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/repeat.html#debug-scripts) and then `step` through vim startup scripts to see what is going on.

Comment: @kit:  The code in your post has spaces before and after the equals sign in your `set guifont` statement.  If it's really that way in your vimrc then take the spaces out, they're not valid around equals sign in set statements (actually I think a space before the equals is okay, but not after).

Answer (score 143, accepted):

Place this in `.gvimrc`:

```
set guifont=Monaco:h12
```

Note the lack of spaces around the equals sign.

Comment: You can also just put this in your `.vimrc` file.

Comment: I changed to use Monaco:h12 and the torte color scheme, and it works well.

Comment: Having added that to `~/.vimrc` there is no effect on the font actually usedin `macvim`

Answer (score 98):

If you need to set a font with spaces in the name, [use backslashes](http://josh.gourneau.com/blog/2010/11/16/how-to-set-a-default-font-aka-guifont-in-your-gvimrc/) in your `.gvimrc`:

```
set guifont=Fira\ Code:h12
```

Comment: Do you use this font in general for programming?

Comment: I swear by it, yes.  In addition to a 'retina display' my eye strain has dropped to nearly-zero

Comment: This is **really helpful** especially when you need set up powerline fonts.

Answer (score 28):

The most complete answer should be this:

```
set guifont=Source\ Code\ Pro\ ExtraLight:h18
```

I looked around and each answer and tutorial I found didn't specify how to set the typeface.

After setting your font manually using the Font window, if you are unsure exactly what to put type:

```
:set guifont
```

This will show you the exact string value you need to put in your .vimrc file, including the typeface.

Answer (score 8):

Attach my fonts setting.

```
" - font type and size setting.
if has('win32')
    set guifont=Consolas:h12   " Win32.
elseif has('gui_macvim')
    set guifont=Monaco:h14     " OSX.
else
    set guifont=Monospace\ 12  " Linux.
endif
```

Answer (score 4):

To deal with not just English characters, you can put this in your `.vimrc` file (`guifontwide` deals with Chinese characters):

```
if has("gui_running")
    set guifont=Consolas:h14
    set guifontwide=Hiragino\ Sans\ GB
    set linespace=2
endif
```

Comment: I'm guessing `wide` means each character is encoded by more than 8 bits, hence it's wide? Or does it actually appear wide?

Answer (score 3):

If you're on Mac, add these lines to your `~/.vimrc`:

```
set gfn=Monaco:h13
set linespace=2
```